# Passing property from one "view" to other view's viewmodel in MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, design-patterns

Im new to MVVM and have small problem. I have two user controls: parent and child(with view, viewmodel, model classes). And need to pass some properties from parent to child. For now ive managed it by writing such code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CallbackActionProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("CallbackAction", typeof (Action), 
        typeof (ChildView), new PropertyMetadata(default(Action)));

public Action CallbackAction
{
  get { return (Action) GetValue(CallbackActionProperty); }
  set
  {
    SetValue(CallbackActionProperty, value);
    ((ChildViewModel)this.DataContext).CallbackAction = value; // Change ViewModel property too
  }
}
```

This is dependency property in `ChildView` and on its set i also set its `ViewModel`'s property. After that i access that dependency property from `ParentView` and set the `CallbackAction`-> that sets the `CallbackAction` in Child's ViewModel.
Code:

```
  this.Loaded += (sender, args) => childUc.CallbackAction = ((ParentViewModel) this.DataContext).RefreshStatuses;
```

`childUc` is usercontrol, located on parent and represented by `ChildView`.
   Code is ugly, so i hope to see better practice in terms of not breaking pattern. 
  Thank you.

Comment: @Mario Vernari, what is the right way to make the thing ive tried to  describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep - this code is pretty ugly. In fact I am struggling to work out exactly what it does!

One of the main tenants of the MVVM pattern is that the ViewModel should be unit testable and it should be possible to execute it without the view. When faced with this kind of problem, think about the view Model alone and ignore the view.

Your ParentViewModel has a reference to the ChildViewModel, you can make this a two way relationship by having the ParentViewModel provide a reference to itself when you create the ChildViewModel. This means that from the ChildViewModel you can execute any public method on the ParentViewModel.

With this in mind, you should be able to solve your problem!

(Also, you should not add logic in your dependency property getter or setter, this code may or may not be called depending on how your dependency property value is set.)

Comment: Mmm, nice suggestion! Sure i can create Parent's interface and pass a reference of that interface type to Child(i can have many "different" parent usercontrols for that child one). Thank you, i'll try. The suggestion about thinking of just ViewModel is best i think. Sure it must work without View.

Comment: Yes, passing an interface to the ChildViewModel that only has the methods it should be able to invoke sounds like a nice idea.

Comment: The children should never know who's their parent, but the parent does. If you want to "communicate" something from any descendant upward, you should use a Command. That allow to exchange data toward the ancestry without any coupling.

Comment: @MarioVernari I strongly object! if you have an OrderViewModel and OrderLineViewModel which have parent => child relationship there is nothing wrong with them being tightly coupled and the relationship being bi-directional. Would you ever want to use OrderViewModel in any other context? No! Sure, a Command might make you feel like you are using more elegant code, but a direct invocation from child to parent within the view model is much simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question/problem, but if you are coupling two VM, I also agree that's totally right. In the question above, the guy is referring to a view and a viewmodel...either I can't read correctly, or I'd keep decoupled. Fully respecting any other viewpoint!

Comment: @MarioVernari I think because the question is a bit vague we have both misunderstood each other! Either way, I think the OP needs to focus more on solving problems within the view model and less on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Do not write any logic in setter or getter of `DependencyProperty` because it called by the Framework in orher ways, not directly through the set/get accessors. This is a must rule.

Also string

```
((ChildViewModel)this.DataContext).CallbackAction = value;
```

introduced tied coupling between current View and underlying ViewModel type, this is not a MVVM principle.

In case of View dependency you should consider passing of properties using bindings in XAML, otherwise ParentViewModel should has injected a ChildViewModel through constructor. So they should be designed to indicate that ParentViewModel has a Child one...